# Loading(automated) datatables which are connected to multiple excel tabs of the same workbook

Tags: spotfire

Hi Spotfire gurus I have a spotfire dashboard which has many datatables. Each datatable is an excel tab and all of those excel tabs are from the same excel workbook.
[Data tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EQqQ.jpg)

[image]

My problem is that whenever the source filename is changed, spotfire tries to connect to the source by asking to locate the file.
so for 10 data tables i get 10 separate prompts which is quite annoying.
[Browse new source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWUdi.jpg)

[image]

Is there a way we can automate this step so that I only have to provide the path once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Shaktirajjena- I would suggest using an access database and import these excel files as tables and connect Spotfire to this database. That should solve the problem.

Comment: @ksp585 thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I can't use access as the spotfire dashboard is to be used by other users. Can we somehow create a parameterised/foreach iteration which goes through the sheets like its possible with SSIS?

Comment: maybe this is a silly question, but have you considered not changing the name of the file? :)

Comment: @niko thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the name of the file will keep changing every month e.g "file_20171124" will become "file_20171125". So I was wondering if there is a way to parameterise the file path and fix sheet names?

Comment: e.g "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Analytics\file_20171124" will change but sheet1,sheet2,sheet3 will be fixed.

Comment: I'd run a batch script to change the file names. This is really the easiest solution. You can't expect Spotfire to know what the name will change to. Listen to @niko, his comment is invaluable.